# Cloud ML-Engine Quota between P100 and K80

Tags: google-cloud-ml

The Cloud ML-Engine Quota documentation mentions:

```
Total concurrent number of GPUs: This is the maximum number of GPUs in concurrent use, split per type as follows:

Concurrent number of Tesla K80 GPUs: 30.
Concurrent number of Tesla P100 GPUs: 30.
```

According to this I should be able to run 60 jobs at the same time as long as they are split 30/30 between these two types of GPU.

In practice, after starting 30 P100 jobs my K80 jobs are left in the queue and are not getting scheduled.
Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

The jobs started on their own after 1 hr. I did have both P100 and K80 jobs running eventually, just took a while for the K80 jobs to start.

Comment: We queue new jobs when the current resource usage is equal or exceeding your project quota. Can you share the job ids with us via cloudml-feedback@google.com please?

Comment: We log why your job was queued at the beginning of your job logs. Please check them as well.

Comment: Sent the info to cloudml-feedback@
The logs at the start only mention:
`2019-01-31 09:52:56.977 PST service Job <JobId> is queued.`
Followed by:
`2019-01-31 11:03:43.165 PST Waiting for job to be provisioned.`

Nothing else in the middle of these two.